# List design in functional languages

Tags: list, functional-programming

I've noticed that in functional languages such as Haskell and OCaml you can do 2 actions with lists. First you can do `x:xs` where x is an element ans xs is a list and the resulting action is we get a new list where x is appended to the beginning of xs in constant time. Second is `x++y` where both x and y are lists and the resulting action is we get a new list where y gets appended to the end of x in linear time with respect to the number of elements in x.
   Now I'm no expert in how languages are designed and compilers are built, but this seems to me a lot like a simple implementation of a linked list with one pointer to the first item. If I were to implement this data structure in a language like C++ I would find it to be generally trivial to add a pointer to the last element. In this case if these languages were implemented this way (assuming they do use linked lists as described) adding a "pointer" to the last item would make it much more efficient to add items to the end of a list and would allow pattern matching with the last element.

My question is are these data structures really implemented as linked lists, and if so why do they not add a reference to the last element?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they really are linked lists.  But they are immutable.  The advantage of immutability is that you don't have to worry about who else has a pointer to the same list.  *You* might choose to write `x++y`, but somewhere else in the program might be relying on `x` remaining unchanged.

People who work on compilers for such languages (of whom I am one) don't worry about this cost because there are plenty of other data structures that provide efficient access:

- A functional queue represented as two lists provides constant-time access to both ends and amortized constant time for `put` and `get` operations.
- A more sophisticated data structure like a *finger tree* can provide several kinds of list access at very low cost.
- If you just want constant-time append, John Hughes developed an excellent, simple representation of lists as functions, which provides exactly that.  (In the Haskell library they are called `DList`.)

If you're interested in these sorts of questions you can get good info from Chris Okasaki's book *Purely Functional Data Structures* and from some of Ralf Hinze's less intimidating papers.

Comment: What about in the case of managing large strings such as a text buffer in a text editor? In this case it is very likely that 2 large strings will need to be concatenated, but since strings are natively provided as lists of characters using one of these data structures would mean pretty much re-implementing all the string functions.

Comment: Text editors use different data structures to manage large strings.  [Ropes](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/90/) are a good candidate.

Answer (score 4):

You said:

> Second is `x++y` where both x and y are
>   lists and the resulting action is y
>   gets appended to the end of x in
>   linear time with respect to the number
>   of elements in x.

This is not really true in a functional language like Haskell; y gets appended to a *copy* of x, since anything holding onto x is depending on it not changing.

If you're going to copy all of x anyway, holding onto its last node doesn't really gain you anything.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are linked lists. In languages like Haskell and OCaml, you don't add items to the end of a list, period. Lists are immutable. There is one operation to create new lists — cons, the `:` operator you refer to earlier. It takes an element and a list, and creates a new list with the element as the head and the list as the tail. The reason `x++y` takes linear time is because it must cons the last element of `x` with `y`, and then cons the second-to-last element of `x` with *that* list, and so on with each element of `x`. None of the cons cells in `x` can be reused, because that would cause the original list to change as well. A pointer to the last element of `x` would not be very helpful here — we still have to walk the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

++ is just one of dozens of "things you can do with lists". The reality is that lists are so versatile that one rarely uses other collections. Also, we functional programmers almost never feel the need to look at the last element of a list - if we need to, there is a function last.

However, just because lists are convenient this does not mean that we do not have other data structures. If you're really interested, have a look at this book http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf (Purely Functional Data Structures). You'll find trees, queues, lists with O(1) append of an element at the tail, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a bit of an explanation on how things are done in Clojure](http://clojure.org/functional_programming#Functional%20Programming--Immutable%20Data%20Structures):

> The easiest way to avoid mutating state is to use immutable data structures. Clojure provides a set of immutable lists, vectors, sets and maps. Since they can't be changed, 'adding' or 'removing' something from an immutable collection means creating a new collection just like the old one but with the needed change. Persistence is a term used to describe the property wherein the old version of the collection is still available after the 'change', and that the collection maintains its performance guarantees for most operations. Specifically, this means that the new version can't be created using a full copy, since that would require linear time. Inevitably, **persistent collections are implemented using linked data structures**, so that the new versions can share structure with the prior version. **Singly-linked lists and trees are the basic functional data structures**, to which Clojure adds a hash map, set and vector both based upon array mapped hash tries.

(emphasis mine)

So basically it looks you're mostly correct, at least as far as Clojure is concerned.